# JavaFX set cell colour depending on cell Value

Tags: java, javafx-8

Hello everybody I was wondering if there was a way of setting the color of a cell in a table in javaFX depending on the value of that cell.

I know there is a way but you have to iterate through the columns.

Does a function like `cell.setColor(GREEN)` or with a css file exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hello,*
    Normally you cannot get instance of table cell, so you need to create custom `TableCell` class, and you can write some code like mentioned below to change based on the conditions you specify. The following is the example of how to change style based on a condition. You need to override the method called `updateItem()` in your code. Don't forget.

```
@Override
protected void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (item == null || empty) {
        setText(null);
        setStyle(""); // set cell style
    } else {
        if (checkCondition) {
            setTextFill(Color.CHOCOLATE);
            setStyle("-fx-background-color: red;");// set your css style here if condition is true
        } else {
            setTextFill(Color.BLACK);
            setStyle(""); // reset the style if condition is false.
        }
    }
}
```